# Woher stammt der schwäbische Begriff "Kugelfuhr"?

Tags: etymology, dialect, swabian

Im Schwäbischen hört man nicht selten den Begriff "*Kugelfuhr"* für eine schwierige oder umständliche Angelegenheit:

> *Das war vielleicht eine **Kugelfuhr** bis dieser Turm statisch gerechnet und genehmigt war. Auf dieser einzigen Kugel ruhen 80 Tonnen Gewicht des Turms, die Spannkräfte der Seile und die Windkräfte und gelegentlich auch noch ein, zwei Tonnen Besucher.Es ist der Fuß des Killesbergturms in Stuttgart.*<sup>[Suttgarter Nachrichten](http://foto.stuttgarter-nachrichten.de/gallery.php?id=40332)</sup>

Laut Wikipedia soll der Begriff aus dem militärischen Gebrauch stammen:

> **Das ist eine Kugelfuhr** — Das ist sehr schwierig zu bewerkstelligen. Munitionstransporte an die Front stellten eine gewaltige logistische Herausforderung dar und mussten gut vorbereitet bzw. abgesichert werden.<sup>[Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_deutscher_Redewendungen)</sup>

Ich bin mir aber fast sicher, dass diese Wikipedia Erklärung falsch ist, handelt es sich hier doch um einen alten Begriff aus dem schwäbischen Dialekt, der aus Zeiten stammt, in denen "Munitionstransporte" keine Rolle gespielt haben dürften.

Hat jemand eine Idee, woher sich der Begriff *"Kugelfuhr"* ableiten könnte? Wird dieser Begriff (oder ein ähnlicher) auch außerhalb Schwabens verstanden?

Comment: Mein Papa bezeichnete mit Gugelfuhr wenn wir Kinder es mal wieder mit dem Unfug zu toll trieben.

Comment: Ich kenne eigentlich die *Kugelfuhr* aus dem Schwäbischen als etwas, das mit großem Aufwand zu einem Mißerfolg (oder zumindestens zu weniger Erfolg als erhofft) geführt hat. Von daher erscheint mir die Verwendung im Zeitungsartikel ein bißchen abwegig (Immerhin steht der Turm auch heute noch...). Die Tatsache, dass es sich hier technisch tatsächlich um eine Kugel handelt, war wohl zu verlockend für den Schreiber.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ich zitiere hier von [deacademic.com](http://idiome.deacademic.com/1612/Kugelfuhr):

> Der Ausdruck ist bereits in mittelhochdeutscher Zeit als ›gogelvuore‹
>   im Sinne von mutwilligem Treiben, lärmender Lustbarkeit, Narrenpossen
>   bezeugt, wobei bereits die Bedeutung von ›gogel‹ = Scherz, Posse und
>   ›gugel‹ = Narrenkappe, eigentlich Obergewand mit Kapuze, das auf
>   lateinisch ›cuculla‹ zurückgeht, vermischt worden sind. Parallele
>   Ausdrücke dazu wie ›Gugelfahrt‹ und ›Gugelfeuer‹ wurden später
>   gebildet.

Wobei die heutige Bedeutung wohl eher der aus dem Rotwelschen zuzuschreiben sein dürfte (was auch dann in gewissem Maße zum S21 Artikel passt): Quelle [deacademic.com](http://idiome.deacademic.com/1612/Kugelfuhr)

> Das Wort ist auch im Rotwelschen meist als ›Kugelfuhr‹ reich bezeugt
>   und bezeichnet auch dort geräuschvolle Späße, provozierte
>   Streitigkeiten und lärmendes Durcheinander bei Zänkereien und
>   Aufläufen, die man geschickt zu seinem Vorteil nutzen konnte. Die
>   heutige abgewandelte Bedeutung der Redensart ist wohl von daher zu
>   verstehen, denn herausfordernde Zänkereien und Narrenpossen
>   verursachen eben für den Betroffenen Umstände, Schwierigkeiten und
>   Verzögerungen.

Comment: Welcher S21-Artikel? Der im vom OP zitierten Artikel erwähnte Killesbergturm hat doch nun wirklich nichts mit dem Bahnhof zu tun.

Answer (score 3):

[Grimms Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GK15624) führt das auf Gaukelfuhre (= gauklerisches treiben) zurück. Das passt allerdings von der Bedeutung her nicht so recht auf die Textstellen (so ein hin- und her wie bei Stuttgart 21 hatten sie wohl nicht).

Ich kannte das Wort vorher nicht.

Comment: Ich verstehe die Anspielung auf Stuttgart 21 nicht. Aber ich würde auch nicht allzu sehr darauf wetten, dass die Textstellen den Begriff 100% korrekt verwenden (falls es überhaupt noch eine genaue, mehr oder minder allgemein anerkannte Bedeutung gibt). Der Autor des Zitats aus den Stuttgarter Nachrichten hat sicherlich auch wegen der Anspielung auf die Kugel des Turms dieses Wort gewählt.

Comment: @fzwo: *Kugelfuhr* wird in Zusammenhang mit schwierig zu bewältigen Aufgaben sehr gerne genommen. Auf Stuttgart21 paßt *Kugelfuhr* also recht gut.

Comment: @Takkat Danke für die Aufklärung. Mir war nur nicht ganz klar, wo S21 auf einmal herkam, und ich dachte, ich hätte da irgendeinen lokalen Zusammenhang zwischen dem Turm und S21 im Frageposting übersehen.

Comment: @fzwo Nein, S21 ist mir wegen der Lage in Schwaben eingefallen, und weil es da wirklich etwas närrisch zugeht, entsprechend der Bedeutung im Grimm.

Answer (score 3):

Ich bin der Meinung, dass das alte deutsche Wort Kugelfuhr sich aus Kugel (vom mhd gogel, Gaukler, aus dem It. giocare, spielen, scherzen) und Fuhr (von lat. forum, franz. foire, also Jahrmarkt) zusammensetzt. Es bezeichnet also einen Gauklermarkt bez. wildes Treiben, Durcheinander.
In dieser Bedeutung kenne ich das Wort von klein auf: Wenn die Lautstärke und das Durcheinander beim Spielen mit Freunden oder Geschwistern überhand nahm, konnten meine Mutter schon man nachfragen: Was hond denn ihr do henna fer a Kuglfuhr?

Answer (score 2):

Also ich kenne das Wort Kugelfuhr auch als eine schwierig zu bewältigende Aufgabe. Und mir wurde es damals, als ich noch jung war, von einem alten, schwäbischen Bauern lachend so erklärt: "Versuch mal eine Ladung Kugeln auf einem Fuhrwerk zum Markt zu bringen, dann weisch, was schwierig isch!" Dabei spielte es gar keine Rolle ob man das wirklich machen wollte und woraus die Kugeln sein könnten. Es war ein Sinnbild! Mit einem Leiterwagen über holprige Wege ist es schier unmöglich Kugeln ohne weitere Hilfsmittel zu transportieren.

Answer (score 0):

Meines Erachtens kommt "Kugelfuhr" aus dem Französischem. Es hat nichts mit Kanonenkugeln zu tun und nichts mit Fuhren (Transporten). Eine "carrefour" ist eine "Wegkreuzung" oder ein "Ort der Begegnung". Daher auch der Name eines französischen Supermarkts: "Carrefour".

Comment: Aber wie kommt man dann von der Wegkreuzung zu einem schwierigen Unternehmen?

Comment: This is a tempting explanation because at a "carre"-four the meeting takes place in an orderly way, but at a "kugel"-four the coming-together is all jumbled up. Like Ox6d64, however, I would still like some substantiation for this.

Answer (score -2):

1. *Kugel*, das runde Ding, scheint lautlich nah bein mittelhochdeutsch *kule, kaule* oder ähnlichem zu stehen (mittelniederdeutsch *kūle* "runder, knotenförmiger oder verdickter Gegenstand", Pfeifer/DWDS: “Kuhle”), vgl. *kullern*. Die Zusammenhänge sind nicht geklärt, zumal für *Kugel* keine gesicherte Etymologie zu Rate gezogen werden kann:

   - im althochdeutsch nicht belegt, kann Vergleich mit engl. *cudgel* als Zufall gelten, denn das ist eben *Keule* neben *Bumskaule* (“Schilfrohrkolben”), während Verwechslungsgefahr mit *Kegel*, *kegeln* besteht. Dies stellt Kluge (20. Aufl.) zu *Kufe*. EWA spricht schlicht von "expressive
     Gemination bei Wörtern für Rundes." (Lühr *et al.*, EWA: *koggo*¹ https://ewa.saw-leipzig.de/articles/koggo1/de#koggo1).
2. Natürlich steht griechisch *kyklos* (über Französisch zu *Zyklus*) sinnverwandt gegenüber, selbst wortverwandt mit engl. *wheel*, vgl. insb. *wheelbarrow*; *barrow* auch ‘Fuhre, Ladung’ wie niederländisch *wagen*, quasi *Wagenladung* (en.Wiktionary).

   Das Deutsche Wörterbuch verzeichnet ebenso *wiel*³ “Rad”. In anderer Bedeutung scheint es "ins hd. eingedrungen und bei nd. beeinfluszten dichtern häufig bezeugt […]" gleichzusetzen zu sein mit *kolk*, etwa "'tiefes, durch einen deichbruch ausgewühltes wasserloch'" (s.v. DWB: [wiel](https://www.dwds.de/wb/dwb/wiel)), das zu mnd. *kūle* gezählt werden könnte. Davon gehe ich aus.

   Übrigens kann auch in der Bedeutung *wiel*² “schleier, kopftuch” (DWB) eine Gleichsetzung mit *verkugeln*² verstanden werden: “*andere schreibung* für vergugeln ([…]) mit einer kaputze verkleiden” (DWB: [verkugeln](https://www.dwds.de/wb/dwb/kugel#GV02303)). Zwischen *hüllen* und *hohl* (vgl engl. *hole*) ist jedoch ein Unterschied zu machen (vgl. Pfeifer, DWDS).
3. Ebenso ist *Gülle* ehemals “1. Wasserlache, Tümpel, bes. von Regen gebildet, gleichviel ob klar oder trüb, dann Kotlache, Sumpf; Ansammlung von Jauche” (Schweizerisches Idiotikon: [Güllen<sup>n</sup>](https://digital.idiotikon.ch/idtkn/idmobil.htm#!page/20222/mode/1up)).
4. Insoweit scheint das Thema klar wie Kloßbrühe. Ich denke da zuerst an *Patsche* ("‘Straßenschmutz’ (Anfang 18. Jh.);" Pfeifer/DWDS), *in der Patsche sitzen*.

   Siehe insoweit auch ahd. *koggo*² "Fäulnis, Verwesung; *rancor*", insb. elsässisch *kog* "alter Gaul" neben schwäbisch *kog* "krepiertes Tier, kranker Mensch", vorarlbergisch *kog(e)* “Aas,
   verendetes Tier” usw. (lt. EWA vielleicht zu *kogge*¹, s.o.).

Es ist im Grunde irrelevant, ob da irgendein etymologischer Zusammenhang besteht. Das ist doch *kacke*. Henning Köckerbeck oder Ortschaften mit Namen wie *Pietzpuhl* (etwa Jauchegrube, anders *Ringelpietz*) sehen das sicher genauso.

Ignoriert man jedoch spekulative Küchenpsychologie (ich hab da schon mal was vorbereitet) und Volksmund (@user10799's Antwort in allen Ehren), sieht es wieder anders aus.

5. Um bei dem Beispiel zu bleiben, das "Tortur" bedeutet, riecht es nach Behördenwillkür.

   > Das war vielleicht eine Kugelfuhr bis dieser Turm statisch gerechnet und genehmigt war.

   Dabei ist zu bemerken, dass *Willkür* im Ursprung nicht so negativ besetzt war wie im heutigen Verfassungsrecht. Es betrifft schlicht kuratierte Vorschriften maßgeblicher Rechtssubjekte.
6. Siehe ferner *willfährig* mit anderer Bedeutung unter Einfluss von
   fahren. En.WT betont: "with *vāren* = to strive; the second part is not identical with German *fahren.*". DWDS genauer (Hervorhebung meinerseits):

> zu mhd. *vāren* ‘feindlich trachten, nachstellen, streben, fürchten’ (s. *Gefahr*). Doch bereits in der mhd. Fügung erfolgt Anschluß an mhd. *varn* ‘fahren’; daher (vereinzelt) auch starke Flexion (***willfuhr***, noch Ende 18. Jh.).

> https://www.dwds.de/wb/willfahren

6. Ebenso steht anders als oben *verkugeln*¹: “durch eine kugel bestimmen. so wurden in früherer zeit die rathsstellen in Frankfurt verkugelt, d. h. durch ziehen einer goldenen kugel bestimmt […]” (DWB: [verkugeln](https://www.dwds.de/wb/dwb/kugel#GV02303)). Grimms Märchen sind jedoch mit Vorsicht zu genießen.

   Die Ähnlichkeit zu *Wahl* ist nunmehr offensichtlich. Der Zusammenhang mit *wollen* und *Wille* (bspw. bei Pfeifer/DWDS) ist positiv zu bewerten. *Küren* wie in *Willkür* soll ähnliches bedeuten, doch die Einordnung ist geschichtlich nicht ganz sauber.
7. Lautlich ist die Analyse schier unmöglich. Insbesondere hat Allemanisch ein verbales K-Präfix erhalten, so dass im wesentlichen *† gelfahr* zu bedenken ist. Im westromanischen wird g für germanisch w gesetzt (*Guilliam, William*). Damit ist ein lautlicher Anschluss an *Willfahr* zumindest denkbar.

   Andererseits schwindet früheres g (vgl. *gain, gagner*), so auch regional *goulle* usw. < *Kugel*; NB: “die Formen mit ü erklären sich vielleicht aus elsässischen Formen mit ü (*küwl* u.ä.)”, vielleicht auch altlothringisch *gourel* (FEW bd. 16, p. 429, s.v. [Kugel](https://www.dwds.de/wb/dwb/kugel#GV02303)).

   Hierher gehört sicherlich auch *kübeln* " viel trinken, besonders Alkohol" (DWDS) bzw. “kotzen, ausschütten" (m.M.n.), *es schüttet wie aus Kübeln* (zu lat. *cupa* “Fass", Herkunft ungewiss, vgl. *Kufe* bei Wiktionary).

Besonders Anschaulich ist das nicht. Die angesprochenen Wortwurzeln weisen zum Teil erhebliches Alter auf. Einige sind zwar lautmalerisch und dementsprechend schwer nachzuvollziehen, und vorallem der schriftsprache fremd und daher kaum nachzuweisen. Andersherum sind Redensarten wie hier oft undurchsichtig ohne einen offensichtlich lautmalerischen Eindruck zu erwecken. Häufig vermischen sich diese Eindrücke jedoch.

Ich finde es jedenfalls überhaupt nicht schwer, Behördenwillkür mit Kackscheiße gleichzusetzen – poppycock, bullshit halt.

Answer (score -4):

It's funny how similar this is in sound and meaning to the English "clusterf*ck", which although I've heard it here and there, is apparently a military slang word. It seems the proposed German derviation is in reference to a military operation that was notorious for being screwed up, which is pretty much exactly the American usage of the corresponding term. It's a question as to which came first, the chicken of the egg, or whether they evolved independently?

Comment: The point I have is that I very much doubt that *Kugelfuhr* is military derived.

Comment: I see. But you don't seem to have explained the source of your skepticism, unless I'm missing something. Is there some reason you don't buy the military explanation?

Comment: I don't really see any resemblance between the tow words; not in pronunciation and certainly not in meaning of the original individual words.

Comment: @MartyGreen: I have seen so many errors in Wikipedia. In this case the word may have also been used in a military context but it is one of the old dialect words; far more widely used than it could have originated from a military slang. See also starblue's reference to Grimm where not only there is no military context but also the orgin from Middle High German *gougelvuore* mentioned. This seems to be far more plausible. Nevertheless thank you for discussing a possible connection with cluster**ck.